# How to individually change colors in an array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

basically I'm doing an Ionic 5 application where I show some information from an array into an  and when you click it's supposed to change the color of the background, but when I click it changes the color of all the cards, not the only one I clicked.

This is the part of .ts for the color change:

```
  private buttonColor: string = "light";

  someAction() {
    this.buttonColor = "primary";
  }
```

And this is the .html:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let A of Animales">

        <ion-card [color]="buttonColor" (click)="someAction()" tappable>

          <ion-card-content>

            <ion-title>{{A.nombre}}</ion-title>
            <div><img src="{{A.imagen}}"></div>
            <p>{{A.nombre}} {{A.raza}} es un {{A.especie}}. Su alimentación es a base de
              {{A.alimentacion}},
              por lo general viven en {{A.ecosistema}}.</p>

          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All buttons are changing color because you are using only one variable `buttonColor` as the source of data, and you are modifying this when any button is clicked.

You have to uniquely identify the button you are clicking, and then change the color of only that button.

In your component, create an array `buttonColors` with same length as your `Animals` array.

```
private buttonColors: string[];

// After 'Animals' data is available, initialize this array.
this.buttonColors = new Array(Animales.length).fill("light");
```

Modify `*ngFor` to include an index, and pass this index to the click event handler function.

```
  <ion-col *ngFor="let A of Animales; let i = index">
     <ion-card [color]="buttonColors[i]" (click)="someAction(i)" tappable>
      ...
      ...
    </ion-card>
  </ ion-col>
```

Modify the click event handler function to only change clicked button's color.

```
someAction(i) {
  this.buttonColors[i] = "primary";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because button color is same for all the cards, A simple solution would be to add a color to Animals array

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let A of Animales">
   <ion-card [color]="A.buttonColor || 'light'" (click)="someAction(A)" tappable>
```

and modify the someAction function to receive the animal

```
someAction(animal) {
  animal.buttonColor = "primary";
}
```

If you want you could also keep a separate array of colors but then instead of passing the animal to someAction pass the index

Answer (score 0):

> Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-change-button-color-mbaxgb?file=pages/home/home.ts)

```
  Animales = [{
    nombre: "Hellow",
    raza: "Hellow"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Hellow",
    raza: "Hellow"
  },{
    nombre: "Hellow",
    raza: "Hellow"
  },{
    nombre: "Hellow",
    raza: "Hellow"
  },

  ]
  buttonColor =['secondary','dark','danger'];
```

.html

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let A of Animales ;let i = index">
        <ion-card [color]="buttonColor[i]" (click)="someAction(i)" tappable>
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-title>{{A.nombre}}</ion-title>
            <div><img src="{{A.imagen}}"></div>
            <p>{{A.nombre}} {{A.raza}}
              </p>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```